# Customizing box text

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way to write custom text inside the name box?

For example when you add the name box it will add the two boxes and in them there are faint words saying 'first' and 'last'. The reason I want to change these is because I'm creating contact for other languages.

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

We are actively testing our localization release, which is scheduled for release in late January to early February.  This release will include support for most countries and currencies of the world and thirteen languages.  You can follow the progress of this feature on our Idea Board: [International Date, Number, Currency, Time Zone & Language Support](https://trello.com/c/yd97bUeA).  You can also learn more about our plans by reading my three-part blog series on the topic, starting with: [Taking on the World, By Going Local – Part 1: Why Now?](http://blog.cognitoapps.com/taking-on-the-world-by-going-local-%e2%80%93-part-1-why-now).  Here is how you will configure localization settings for each form:

[image]

In addition to localized support for thirteen languages, we will also now fully support customization of all user interface text and error messages.  This means, that as long as you are embedding our forms, you will be able to add a small bit of simple JavaScript to fully customize any system-defined text on your forms.  Localization of the name placeholder text would look something like this:

`Cognito.resources["name-first"] = "First";`

Comment: Our international release is now live!  This also means that while embedding you can override any system prompts as shown in the example above.